# "React does not recognize the prop on a DOM element" in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

> React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

This is the code in question:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    NavLink
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./AdminPage.css";

export default class AdminPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <nav>
                        <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to="/admin/books" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Books</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to="/admin/branches" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Branches</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to="/admin/members" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Members</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <Switch>
                        <div> <!-- this appears to be the element that is receiving a "computedMatch" property -->
                            <Route exact path="/admin/books">
                                Books
                            </Route>
                        </div>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

because `Switch` passes `computedMatch` to the first child that meets one of 2 conditions:

1. has either a `path` or a `form` prop that matches the current location.
2. has none of these 2 props (`path`, `form`)

The element in question in your code is that `div`.

Inside the render method of [Switch.js](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js), you will see this:

```
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
  if (match == null && React.isValidElement(child)) {
    element = child;

    const path = child.props.path || child.props.from;

     match = path
       ? matchPath(location.pathname, { ...child.props, path })
       : context.match;
   }
 });

return match
  ? React.cloneElement(element, { location, computedMatch: match })
  : null;
```

And since `computedMatch` isn't a legal DOM attribute/property, you get the warning.

[Unknown Prop Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html)

Answer (score 0):

Only when running the Jest test would I encounter this warning.

```
render(<Popup><div>test</div></Popup>);
```

The Poupup React component uses `React.cloneElement` in its implementation to pass props down into the rendered child.
In the test since I was passing a regular HTML element the props contained unrecognised HTML properties.

The fix was to render the test with a proper React element instead:

```
const TestElement = () => <div>test</div>
render(<Popup><TestElement /></Popup>);
```